# Custom Http Handlers in ASP .Net MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httphandler

A strange problem arises. Though it is working as expected but it is somehow annoying.
I tried to build an image handler using Custom Http Handler.So that whenever a user requests for a URL Like

```
http://localhost:49376/privateimage/dog
```

a dog image is dispalyed. If he opts for a cat

```
http://localhost:49376/privateimage/cat
```

a cat.jpg is displayed. Here is what I have done so far

```
public class CustomMVCRouteHandler :IRouteHandler //Register our HttpHandler inside our RouteConfig file
{

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new CustomMVCHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

And the handler looks like

```
   public class CustomMVCHandler : IHttpHandler //For this custom HttpHandler we need a RouteHandler which will route our requests
{
    //Create a RequestContext object 
    public RequestContext requestContext{get;set;}

    //Create a parameterized constructor for the class and initialize the requestContext object
    public CustomMVCHandler(RequestContext reqCon)
    {
        requestContext = reqCon;
    }

    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string requestedAction = context.Request.Url.Segments[2].ToLower(); // Context object is the bridge connecting your
        var routeValues = context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
        if (routeValues.ContainsKey("image") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeValues["image"].ToString()))
        {
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            string xsltPath = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), routeValues["image"].ToString());
            xsltPath = xsltPath + ".jpg";
            context.Response.WriteFile(xsltPath);
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Education & Jobs\ASP .Net MVC\Logs\Log.txt", true);
        sw.WriteLine("The static file requested is -- " + requestedAction);
        sw.WriteLine("Static file requested at -- " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +" "+ requestedAction);
        sw.Close();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Route.config looks like :

```
routes.Add("ImageRoute",new Route("privateImage/{image}",new CustomMVCRouteHandler()));
```

But now the problem I face is sometimes after a Dog image is requested and the image is displayed **when we start typing the URL for cat , before typing it completely and pressing enter only** the handler code is hit again in debugger mode and the page refreshes with the previous dog.jpg image . Same occurs vice-versa also.

I am not completely sure what's happening. But this is what I found out .

[image]

Here even though we just start typing the URL for

```
http://localhost:49376/privateimage/dog
```

the code in debugger mode is hit again .

[image]

and the default home page is displayed.

[image]

What's the reason for this latency ? Do breakpoints have something to do with them ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your issue ?

Comment: @Ken Not really.

Comment: After doing some reading on my own - I think your issue is IsReusable returns true so the handler really never goes away it is reused over and over again for all additional requests or concurrent requests ; any class level variables are maintained - try setting that IsReusable to false. If that cures it - then move your process requests code into something you need to instantiate and can call a dispose method on. That way all your existing variables disappear.